# Create a property writer in SOLR

Tags: java, solr, cassandra, solrj

I need to add a property to return a timestamp, I use below example to test print a sample date in "dataimport.properties" file to get last modified time. And it's not working

dataconfig.xml:

```xml
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"    
driver="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver"    
url="jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/sample"    
user="cassandra"
password="cassandra" 
autoCommit="true"/>    
<document name="content">    
<entity name="defaults" query="SELECT id from sample.contacts" 
deltaImportQuery="select id from sample.contacts where modifiedtime >'${dataimporter.defaults.last_index_time}'  allow filtering" 
deltaQuery="select id from sample.contacts where modifiedtime > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}' limit 1 allow filtering "
autoCommit="true">    
<field column="id" name="id" />  
</entity>   
</document>    
<propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" type="SimplePropertiesWriter"   directory="conf" filename="dataimport.properties"  locale="en-US"/>
</dataConfig>`
```

Comment: Property Writer throws exception **java.io.FileNotFoundException**. Try this `<propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" type="SimplePropertiesWriter"  />` without directory, filename and locale. By Default directory is "conf" and filename is "dataimport.properties".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<propertyWriter dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" type="SimplePropertiesWriter" />
```

You will start getting your **last_index_time** in desired format (**yyyy-MM-dd**) in conf/dataimport.properties.